# Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost: 4200/auth/login

Tags: json, angular, web

I am a total beginner working for a small app as a front-end. I can not compile my codes today (or I can not login in in the app), the error is:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy: `localhost:4200/auth/login`

I tried to changed the code in `proxy.config.json` like following:

```
[ "target": "http://localhost:4200",
    
 "secure": false]
```

I have changed the "secure" to true and the target to `//localhost:8080`. but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is enough code here to reproduce the problem.